# Laptop battery and adapter voltage ratings

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, adapter, efficiency

Considering a 4-cell (laptop) lithium-ion battery, the cell voltages add (since they are in series) to 3.7 V * 4 = 14.8 V. However, the adapter says that it has a 19.5 V DC output. I want to know why is it 19.5 V and not some other value like 14.8 V itself or 24 V for instance?

Also, my adapter says Input: 100-240 V ~ 1.6 A and Output: 19.5 V - 3.33 A (65 W). Does it mean that the adapter efficiency is 65 W/(1.6 A*230V) assuming that the mains voltage is 230 V? Am I actually paying bills for 230*1.6 W or is it that 1.6 A is the maximum current that can be drawn and the actual current varies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The adapter does **not** connect to the laptop's battery directly, there is **always** a **charging control circuit** in between. In laptops this usually is a switching type charging circuit to avoid excessive power (heat) dissipation.

If the power adapter delivered 14.8 V then it would be difficult to impossible to fully charge the battery as there would be no "voltage headroom" left for the charging circuit.

The choice for 19.5 V instead of 24 V might be historical and practical. 19.5 V did the job and maybe 24 V might require components rated for a higher voltage.

The input rating of the power adapter is just that a **rating** which means that the current will not exceed the rated 1.6 A. Usually this maximum current is only reached when you **plug in** the adapter into the mains. During normal operation the current will be much less. How much will depend on how much power is required from the 19.5 V output.

If the adapter would actually continuously consume 1.6 A then it would get extremely hot as it would need to dissipate a lot of power. So no, you will not be paying a bill for 1.6 A.

Comment: I now get the idea. I wanted to ask another question on similar lines. The DC fast chargers for Electric Vehicles have a rating of 200-600 V. Does that mean that this high voltage is applied directly across the battery whose nominal voltage is typically 48 V or 72 V? Wouldn't that heavily degrade the battery?

Comment: @PMD The battery voltage is far higher than that but the rated voltage is not directly applied as an stiff voltage source but rather a CC/CV charger with negotiation.

Comment: If in a laptop the adapter is connected to the battery via a charging circuit, what makes you think that this is **not** the case for an electric vehicle? What do you think would happen if we connect 200 to 600 V DC (with high current capability as we want to charge quickly) directly to a 48 or 72 V battery? **BOOM !!!**

Comment: I did not get this: "via a charging circuit". Isn't it the case that the final voltage applied across the battery is 19.5V?

Comment: No, you're still thinking that the 19.5 V is directly applied to the battery, well **it isn't and for good reasons**. Li-Ion cells have a nominal voltage of about 3.7 V, 4 in series gives 4 x 3.7 V = 14.8 V. A fully charged Li-Ion cell gives about 4.2 V, so 4 cells is then 16.8 V. I you apply 19.5 V instead of that 16.8 V the **you will damage the cells**. Also unexpected things can happen (heat/fire/smoke etc). It is simply not how Li-Ion cells must be treated. They have certain limits which **MUST** be observed. 4.2 V per cell is one limit. The charging circuit takes care of this.

Comment: Ok. But then why call superchargers to be having 600 V rating or so? What exactly does this 600 V have to do with charging the battery?

Comment: Also, is it the case that this 19.5V supply is chopped down to levels between 14.8V and 16.8V depending on the SOC for charging?

Comment: P = V * I, or Power = voltage * current. To quickly charge, the Power needs to be large, you could use a high current and low voltage **but** high current gives **power losses** and thick (expensive) cables and connectors are needed. A high voltage at a modest current is **much more efficient**, less power is lost, cost is lower.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Can you please answer my last two questions? I am really confused now.

Comment: A charging chip isn't generally considered/called a SOC. Often in laptops a PMU IC or a dedicated charging IC is used. These consist of a switched DCDC converter and a microcontroller taking care of currents and voltages. Your confusion stems from lack of knowledge, I suggest that you read some books about subjects you're interested in. At this moment you want to understand things you cannot understand yet as you do not have the background knowledge that you need. Also: don't try to understand "everything" all at once, take small steps and accept some things will be more clear later.

Comment: I just want to understand what that 600 V refers to. Is it that 600 V is applied but the charging control system on interaction with the BMS (battery management system) chops it down to some lower value? By the way, SOC refers to state-of-charge (and not system-on-chip or something else)

Comment: @PMD Where do you get that EV batteries are 48-72V? Modern EVs use pack voltages between 300 and 400 volts. For example, the Nissan Leaf packs are rated for 365 volts nominal.

Comment: And before you ask "but how can a 365 V battery charge from 200 V (or even 120 V AC)": electronic circuits exist to convert almost any voltage into almost any other voltage. So generating 400 V DC from 200 V DC is possible and can be done efficiently thanks to high-voltage switching transistors.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your patience. But, one more question. Can I conclude that there are two charging ports on the car and if one wants to "AC-charge" it, it can be done from an AC source of any voltage (120V, 240V, 400V) on connecting to the AC port? Similarly, if one wants to "DC-charge", it can be done from a DC charging station of any voltage (200v, 400V, 600V) since the power electronic converters inside the car will anyways convert it to required DC level (say 400-450V for a 375V battery)

Comment: *AC vs Dc charge* Nope, that would be too confusing and it isn't needed. DCDC converters always need DC as input. So if you would charge at home from AC, there will be an AC to DC converter (rectifier) somewhere. That's a $2 component so adding it is no issue. For fast charging it is probably more convenient to use DC skipping any extra AC to DC and DC to AC conversions. But the fast charging station will be powered from AC since mains is always AC.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Suppose that my battery's nominal voltage is 375V. Now if I want to charge my battery at a fast charging station which has chargers rated at 800V, how is the charging going to take place? Is the charger itself going to convert it to 400V before delivering the power or is there already a converter inside the car which converts 800V (or any other voltage) to 400V for charging?

Answer (score 1):

For a better idea of how the laptop battery charger ckt works, look at TI BQ24735 Datasheet.  There are large FETs that serve as gating switchings between running of AC power or Battery power.  There are more details, but in short, there is a FET switch that is used by the TI controller to separate the 2 paths of 19V from the Battery Pack.

https://www.ti.com/product/BQ24735#product-details